# Problem with \edef and CJK

Tags: macros

In the following code, it seems that using `\edef` with CJK contents may fail. (I used pdflatex, UTF8 encoding.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
\newcommand{\tiangan}[1]{\ifcase #1%
\or甲\or乙\or丙\or丁\or戊\or己\or庚\or辛\or壬\or癸\fi}

\newcount\fuu\fuu=3
\def\ber{\romannumeral\fuu}
\fuu=4
\ber%iv
\edef\ber{\romannumeral\fuu}% successes in \edef-ining \ber as iv
%\show\ber
\fuu=5%iv
\ber%iv

\def\faa{三}
\def\bor{\faa}
\def\faa{四}
\bor%四
\edef\bor{\faa}% fails in \edef-ining \bor as 四
%\show\bor
\def\faa{五}
\bor%

\def\foo{3}
\def\bar{\tiangan{\foo}}
\def\foo{4}
\bar%丁
\edef\bar{\tiangan{\foo}}% fails in \edef-ining \bar as 丁
%\show\bar
\def\foo{5}
\bar%

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

What is meant in the error message? How to `\edef`ine a macro with CJK characters?

---

Addition on 18 July 2014

Thanks to egreg and Herbert. I tried `\protected@edef` but then `\global` fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
\newcommand{\tiangan}[1]{\ifcase #1%
\or甲\or乙\or丙\or丁\or戊\or己\or庚\or辛\or壬\or癸\fi}
\makeatletter

\def\ber{\romannumeral3}%iii
{%
  \global\edef\ber{\ber\romannumeral4}%iiiiv
  \show\ber
  \ber
}
\show\ber
\ber%iiiiv

\def\bar{\tiangan{3}}%丙
{%
  \global\protected@edef\bar{\bar\tiangan{4}}%丙丁
  \show\bar
  \bar%
}
\show\bar
\bar%丙

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

How should I rewrite so that the effect of `\protected@edef` is global?

Comment: It's not clear why you want to do that. However, `\protected@edef` should be what you're looking for. Remember `\makeatletter` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

Comment: The global version of `\protected@edef` is called `\protected@xdef` (_cf._ `\edef` and `\xdef`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what the `cjk` package does but you can use:

```
\makeatletter
\protected@xdef\bor{\faa}% doesn't fail in \edef-ining \bor as 四
\makeatletter
```

and also for the other `\edef`